# Is it plausible for self-destruct button to trigger a countdown?

Tags: science-fiction, spaceships

Inspired by this [question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/70226/why-would-many-future-interstellar-spaceship-designs-come-with-a-self-destruct-b), and [this article](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Self_destruct_system), activating self-destruct mechanism disengage coolant system for the ship's main reactor, which then increases the core temperature and triggers explosion.

However, I find it strange for such sequence to trigger an accurate 10 seconds countdown, especially because destabilizing core does not mean it will explode exactly 10 seconds after the sequence is initiated. It can be on the 8th second, or 12th second.

**So, is it plausible to have a fixed (for example, 10 s) countdown for self-destruct mechanism like this?** If not, why bother displaying/announcing the countdown (so people will panic)?

**Note:** For this question, **I rule out the possibility of forced destruction**, like igniting the core when the countdown reaches zero. You can pick the technology for the core, but it certainly will explode when the sequence is activated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66301/discussion-on-question-by-vylix-is-it-plausible-for-self-destruct-button-to-trig).

Answer (score 73, accepted):

## Yes, it is entirely plausible. But the question is not.

The concept of [**scuttling**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scuttling) is not exactly new, the most (in)famous example being [Cortés](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hern%C3%A1n_Cort%C3%A9s). Scuttling is a function that is sometimes worked into the design and the operating procedures of a ship.

Heck, we even have a scuttling function on spaceships **today**.

For example:

- [SpaceX F9R test ends when rocket tips over and scuttling charges destruct the rocket](https://www.space.com/26921-spacex-reusable-rocket-explodes-over-texas-video.html).
- [Alternate, close-up view (16 seconds into the video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvim4rsNHkQ#t=16s).

Designing the scuttling procedure and mechanism is an engineering task. And no engineer worth their degree would ever design a scuttling procedure that happens willy-nilly by being the subject to random factors. Yet for some mysterious and to me entirely unknown reason, the question and the majority of answers assumes that a future space ship with a scuttling-function would somehow be similar to a contemporary ground based nuclear power reactor without such a function. I have to say: **this is a most unfounded and entirely unnecessary — not to mention unrealistic — assumption**.

Scuttling would — by necessity — be:

1. Controlled, that is to say it happens only **if** the ship's command structure says it will happen.
2. Deterministic; it happens only **when** and **how** the ship's command structure says it will happen, not sooner, nor later, not more violent, not any less.

These are the principles the architects and engineers of the ship will work with. They will not deliver something that happens at random since there is no reason for it, and it would be really poor engineering. And if the normal physical processes of the ship cannot ensure that the ship will destruct at the right time, then they will build in extra mechanisms that help the process along.

So if the customer would say:

> I rule out the possibility of forced destruction

...then I — as an engineer<sub>(*)</sub> — would cross my arms, look them straight in the eyes, and say: **No**... I will **not** design your scuttling function with such a silly and contrived design restraint. Either you let me do my job properly or go find yourself another engineer. Good luck with that...

So to summarize: the assumptions of the question — that scuttling would be left to random uncontrollable processes — are by any and all engineering principles **faulty**. Scuttling will be made controlled and deterministic, and the necessary steps to make it happen **will** be taken. Anything else would simply be incompetent engineering, **and no one will want to go into space on a ship made by incompetent engineers**. Nor would anyone allow management to interfere with the construction of the ship in such a way.

....because [we know what happens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4JOjcDFtBE#t=95) when [management adds silly requirements to a ship project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasa_(ship)#Maiden_voyage).

<sub>(*) Yes, I am an engineer by degree and trade</sub>

Comment: I enjoy reading that last part. Definitely +1 from me.

Comment: This answer is brill - I'd add that a scuttling process is almost certain to be included in any large spaceships in future - after all, if they're capable of travelling fast enough to make their use worthwhile, then they're also a huge risk to static installations like towns, cities, space stations. Scuttling charges allow for destroying the craft prior to serious damage being done should there be a major incident requiring it - better to nuke a billion dollar craft than lose a billion lives.

Comment: @Miller86 Ah, good point. All the more incentive to make the scuttling deterministic since a twenty minute discrepancy between the intended and actual actual moment of destruction is the difference between a [Rapid Scheduled Disassembly](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rapid_unplanned_disassembly) and a planetary catastrophe with millions / billions dead.

Comment: I think there is a 3rd thing that scuttling should be, which is complete.  Blowing up a ship to prevent a crash is only so helpful if large chunks of the ship are still going in basically the same direction, but now at a higher, uncontrollable velocity.  This is also important if the ship is blown up to prevent use/recovery by an enemy force.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian True. So "deterministic" does not only concern **time** but also **mode** of destruction, which can vary wildly between "Salvageable Derelict" to "In yo' FACE EmmEffers!!!"

Comment: @IllusiveBrian I think blowing ship is intended to hopefully spread debris over atmosphere and create a nice meteor shower. More smaller pieces - more area = more heat = less impact - a ship as a whole have a lot less drag and therefore might collide much more spectacularly (I hope you haven't planned to go to Dino Zoo).

Comment: A primary function of a deep space scuttling charge may be to render the ship permanently disabled while weighing as little as possible. Forcing a reactor meltdown seems like an obvious way to do that.

Comment: While I agree with engineering principles presented in this answer, I would like to point out that in Star Trek (or similar setting) this question would be perfectly reasonable. Since people don't get paid there, they have little incentive to educate themselves or do their jobs properly, so half of engineering staff are no better than people grabbed from the street and forced to work at gunpoint (phaserpoint?). Assuming that was not the hiring process in the first place. Evidence include Scotty giving random estimates and a teenager smarter than chief engineer.

Comment: @Miller86 Scuttling charges are useless in space. All you do is change one dangerous piece into entire cloud of debris, travelling at same velocity but now covering larger area, like shotgun blast, except much, much worse. Controlled scuttling will happen only by flying ship into star or planet. Scuttling charges are only useful to break ship apart when attempting to scuttle it on inhabited planet, hoping that debris burns in atmosphere and either doesn't reach surface, or reaches surface in too small fragments to have significant impact on biosphere.

Comment: @Miech To point out... Miller86 did not say "scuttling **charges**", they said "scuttling **device**". And as they also pointed out: a massive object crashing into a planet is liable to do much more damage than a cloud of small objects. Compare the shotgun that you mentioned to a rifle. What is the range of a shotgun compared to the equivalent shot weight for a rifle? Since ballistics roughly obey the cube-square law when it comes to drag, many small dispersed objects of a given collective mass, stop on a much shorter distance than the equivalent singular cohesive mass.

Comment: You can't prevent salvage of abandoned ship, you can only make it impractical, for that, reactor meltdown is not as useful as one think. It would be better to vent reactor coolant (first loop) (or even better: spent fuel) into ships insides to activate and thus permanently irradiate it. Due to radiation damage to electronics and conditions hostile to crew it will become unsalvageable. It would require too much effort to even recycle it, what with having to separate isotopes.

Comment: @Miech What makes you think that the ship's reactor looks anything like the reactors we use today? OP even said "fusion reactor".

Comment: @MichaelK That's why I said that charges would only be useful for scuttling in atmosphere of inhabited planet. In barren one or when scuttling into star, there's no need to bother.

Comment: @MichaelK Fusion reactor would require a whole lot of juice to fire up. Every ship will need fission reactor as igniter and backup power anyway.

Comment: @Miech In the audio book series I am currently listening to ("Expeditionary Force", by Craig Alanson, new book out yesterday, YAY! :D) the setting is such that it is a **requirement of the mission** that if the protagonists need to scuttle the ship, then it must be as vapourized as possible, wiping out the crew down to the last molecule of DNA, in order to not give the enemy any chance to board the ship and/or capture remains of it and investigate, and thereby find out that humans have gone star-hopping. So to that latest comment of yours I say: "lacks imagination". ;)

Comment: @MichaelK Sounds like that series is fiction all right, but severely missing science part.

Comment: @Miech According to you and who else, hm? I find your comments querulous at best and not in any way attempting to improve the answer. The premise in question: when alien life finally visits Earth, it turns out that humans are at least three levels down the tech hierarchy. By sheer luck, humans manage to hijack a space ship and re-purpose it for their own ends. However, if it is discovered that humanity is gallivanting around the galaxy in their own stolen starship, this would put all of Earth in serious jeopardy, as the higher-ups will be very cross with us. Simple, no science violated.

Comment: @MichaelK Sci-Fi requires certain level of realism, or rather plausibility and thorough examination of implications of sci part. For example SW is a model case of space fantasy, it never even heard word "science". Unless series you are mentioning has damn good reason why ship can be destroyed so thoroughly, it's not sci-fi.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66268/discussion-between-michaelk-and-m-i-ech).

Answer (score 25):

With the sorts of self-destruct mechanisms we see portrayed cinematically, there are two different sorts of countdown: time to override the self-destruct command, and time to reach a safe distance to escape the effects of the self-destruct system.

In the first case, the mechanism triggers at the end of the countdown; if you override the self-destruct command in that time, nothing happens. That can, of course, be timed very precisely.

The time to reach a safe distance may be less definite.

Obviously, if you've got no way to override the self-destruct command, and there's an explosion instantly when the mechanism triggers, then there's no distinction between the two types of countdown, and it can be very precise.

Answer (score 11):

Disabling the cooling should not trigger a meltdown or explosion on any kind of reactor. No engineer would design a reactor that catastrophically fails in 10 seconds if the coolant is cut off.

So you have a typical 1 GW fission reactor, that means you generate 10 GJ in 10 seconds worth of electricity and perhaps another 20 GJ in heat, so convert it all to heat and the have 30 GJ -- The energy content of almost 5 barrels of oil. No sane design would permit such a small amount of energy to destroy a reactor. Whether fusion or fission, 1 GW reactors will have a lot of material and 5 barrels of oil worth of energy could certainly heat things up, but they won't be a self-destruct.

Comment: The coolant system is obviously not the only system affected when the sequence is started, however I like that first part very much.

Comment: You might want to talk to Japan about that.  Loss of power to the damper rods and the cooling is what caused that reactor problem.

Comment: @ShadoCat it was much longer than 10s, and no one expected loss of power to *auxiliary* generators — it was, after all, a stationary plant. And they underestimated wave height by 3m in area where everyone believed 10m is **over**estimation. Thus, author is right that no engineer would design such a thing. Fukushima guys designed plant that runs separate generators when main cooling power fails. Rest is just a tragic mistake caused by lack of knowledge, justified by data from previous years.

Comment: "Disabling the cooling should not trigger a meltdown or explosion on any kind of reactor."  Certain types of reactors (like the RBMK at Chernobyl) will explode if they lose coolant for too long.  Modern designs will melt down relatively safely.  While both will probably take longer than 10 seconds, and there are other active or passive safeties in place, cooling is critical for fission reactors to continue being reactors.

Comment: Fukishima had problems with leaking radiation- big difference between what happened there and a massive explosion that would destroy a starship

Comment: @ShadoCat Fukushima is inapplicable here, and the mechanism of destruction was very different.  Please do not simply namedrop stuff like this based on a sliver of stale pop knowledge, at least spend 2 minutes over on Wikipedia refreshing your recall.

Comment: @CarlKevinson The explosion of the Chernobyl reactor was not caused by turning the coolant flow off, it was caused by them stupidly turning it back on again when they realised it was getting too hot.  There comes a point where reintroducing coolant will only avert a meltdown at the cost of a large steam explosion spraying radioactive material everywhere.

Answer (score 8):

So, you need to self destruct your ship at a certain time. But you don't want to rig it with explosives and you don't have an anti-matter reactor, so you can't just turn off containment and have it go BOOM. You need to design a way for your regular ship's system to serve double duty as a reliably timed self destruct.

One option is for your reactor to have no upper bounds as to how much energy it can generate/fuel it can use. You set your self destruct timer and when it reaches zero the computer sets your rector from 100% power output to 100,000% in a nanosecond. It uses a decade worth of fuel instantly and none of the safeties come even *close* to being able to manage the power. KA-BOOM.

That's your best bet. But what happens if your technology doesn't allow you to dump arbitrary amounts of fuel into your reactor at a moment's notice? Maybe flooding the reaction chamber with that much fuel that quickly 'stalls' out your engine?

Then we need to examine what a (conventional) bomb is. It is a very strong container. When the bomb's trigger goes off, the powder burns up *quickly* creating a bunch of heat and pressure. Eventually this pressure becomes too great for the container and it ruptures, releasing all of the stored energy in a big boom. If the container is too strong it won't rupture, and no boom. If it is too weak it will rupture too early with no pressure inside, no boom. If you build the pressure slowly then the container will rupture when it *just barely* has too much pressure, that pressure will be released then there won't be enough pressure left over to make the big boom.

It is a balancing act. And as we went over, you are limited by the fact that your engine design can only build pressure slowly. So if you can only build up heat and pressure slowly, how do you get an explosion?

I'd suggest that you do it backwards. Instead of creating a strong container then building explosive levels of heat and pressure within it, create massive amounts of heat and pressure, then 'shove' it into a container with the self-destruct.

Imagine instead of turning *off* the cooling systems, then self destruct timer turns the cooling to *max*. Slowly you ramp up the reactor. After 5 minutes the reactor is in dire straits, and the cooling systems can barely keep up. Then, when the timer hits zero, All the cooling is shut off. Not just shut off, thrown into reverse, maybe. Perhaps there are explosive bolts in the cooling system that will allow it to instantly seal every system the removes heat and pressure from the reactor.

This won't allow *perfect* nano-second timing the way shutting off anti-matter containment would, but it would probably get fairly close.

Comment: *"when it reaches zero the computer sets your rector from 100% power output to 100,000% in a nanosecond"* That's not really how it tends to work, though; it's the same as when people ask "is it safe to use my 15-volt 3-amp power supply for this device which needs 15 volts 1 amp?" -- a properly functioning device won't suddenly start drawing more power than it needs. (A fixed *current* power supply is a somewhat different matter, but those would present... *hurdles* in a situation like this.) Also note that contemporary fission reactors are slow to adjust; hence used primarily for base power.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling `a properly functioning device won't suddenly start drawing more power than it needs` Generally speaking, a 'properly functioning' device is one that is designed ***not*** to self destruct. That's not the kind of device we're talking about here :)

Comment: Also, yes, some sort of nuclear reactor that can create a steady amount of power per unit of fuel consumption and that can consume any amount of fuel thrown at it isn't very likely considering what we know of them now.

Comment: point of language - wrt fission reactors "critical" is the normal state of affairs, it simply means the reaction is producing the same number of neutrons it is consuming. A super-critical reactor is ramping up, a sub-critical one is backing off.

Comment: on your point about traditional gunpowder bombs: if you have a reactor that works like conventional rocket's combustion chamber but w/ some kind of nuclear reaction instead of chemical combustion ('plausible' only w/ semi-indestructible unobtanium lining or a radically new way to use magnets, but hey..) you could have it able to constrict flow more for higher exhaust velocity at hi speed cruise, so self destruct could just cut power, pinch all the way shut, then full power. Which would be precisely timable

Comment: @JosephRogers Good point about terminology. I was using the term critical to mean 'in a bad state' IE: After you have a heart attack, you are in critical condition. When talking about a nuclear reactor this is obviously confusing with the nuclear physics term. I'll edit.

Comment: @Shane I felt a bit pedantic saying it tbh because of course it's commonly used and understood the way you used it, it just really grates with anyone who knows much about nuclear reactors if characters who should have an understanding of nuclear physics use it that way

Comment: @Joseph Rogers: Well if you add all your unused fuel rods into the reactor quickly you should be able to reach prompt critical, at which point no reasonable amount of cooling can contend anymore.

Comment: @Joshua true, I considered mentioning prompt criticallity before but decided against it for fear of further confusing matters. For the uninitiated, prompt criticallity is when a large amount of fissile material is brought together suddenly to form a "critical mass", which is simply enough material close enough together that natural decay processes give off enough neutrons to start a chain reaction and "go critical" in the nuclear physics sense. Look up the Demon Core for real world (unintentional) prompt criticallity incidents.

Answer (score 5):

It is not plausible for a self-destruct to have a count-down by purely mechanical or chemical means, especially one that could be ***stopped*** at the last second.

***HOWEVER,*** it makes a great deal of sense to have a settable countdown for a triggered self destruct system; knowing when it will happen gives people time to prepare or escape. There are circumstances in war where intentionally giving your life or using your ship as a bomb is the strategic best option: Say to kill an opponent that otherwise is about to gain enough power to win the war, or to deny an opponent intelligence about your ship that can be used against all your other ships, or deny your opponent the chance of flying your ship as a false flag: For example, making it even **more** explosive and flying it directly into your headquarters.

In my career I have worked on military equipment that had built in self-destruct mechanisms, to prevent discovery and/or capture of the technology or secrets.

Comment: Basically, scuttling the ship, in other words

Comment: @Shalvenay Scuttle is **one** purpose, . just sink the ship: Which was done to prevent a ship from being taken and used by the enemy. I think of self-destruct as more like a computer closing a charge on a bit of C4 that destroys a secret-tech sensor, so it cannot be reverse-engineered or removed and used in another device. One could do the same for electronics, disks: A criminal hacker could rig his laptop thusly. In space, self-destruct could be a way to convert all fuel to a bomb: Not just to deny use of the ship, but to destroy other targets too, as a final blow when all is lost anyway.

Comment: Scuttling tech you don't really want the count down though. You want a 'press button, device dies' so the instant they 'break in' you can do it.

Comment: @Sobrique True, but if converting the ship to a bomb to accomplish both (damage and denial of the ship), a countdown for the threat may be useful. basically a restriction of options to the enemy: *We both die or we both live; you have ten seconds to disengage and return control of this ship, or we all die.*

Comment: Yeah, true. I was thinking laptops or computer systems. - Blow the device if they're vulnerable, but not an instant before.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt you could have complete accuracy of detonation time but a minimum time to detonation should entirely possible with a well established reactor design. Most self-destructs also require a dump of raw fuel into an overheated system so reasonable accuracy should be achievable in such a system.

Comment: This was my thought. To me the point of a countdown is that it gives you time to evacuate or cancel it if it's no longer required.
So actually the countdown occurs before any self destruct system is activated, at which point it could be anything from milliseconds to minutes before the actual self destruct occurs (but it should also be all but impossible to stop at this point, preventing enemies from disabling it and taking the ship whole)

Answer (score 3):

The count down is to give cinematic tension.  That's all.

I can see that if the self destruct was not instant (like bombs planted throughout the ship) that the power plant destabilization might, on it's own, trigger warnings.

Also, if it is an instant destruction device, you may wish to give your crew time to evacuate.

Otherwise, it is like putting an LED timer on a bomb.  Who, other than an infantile, grandstanding moron with masochistic tendencies, would let people know how long they have to defuse a bomb?  If I **ever** had a character put a visible timer on a bomb, I'd have the bomb go off when there was still 12 minutes and 34 seconds left on the timer.

Comment: While I agree to a point, there are other uses for countdowns (self destruct and bomb). You put a countdown on a bomb that is _intended_ to be diffused. The countdown is there to pressure whoever it is you are making demands of to capitulate, and also to let them know you are serious. Of course, those kind of situations mostly arise in TV shows or movies so the point may be moot.

Comment: "I am a three second grenade. I will explode in three seconds. Three...two..." **BOOM**

Comment: ShadoCat and @Draco18s have both been spending too much time with the Evil Overlord List [#15](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EvilOverlordList) and perhaps [#136](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EvilOverlordListCellblockA). :-) Warning: TV Tropes links.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, Ah, so you've seen my guidebook.....

Comment: @pojo-guy, yep.  I actually met him once.  The only way to meet him at a con was to have a donor sticker from the blood drive that he made sure was there.

Comment: I actually grew up across the road from Camp Arthur Currie (Currie Barracks by then, CFB Calgary later). When I first read that book, it was to the sound of Chinook helicopters flying over my house and hovering for rappelling (drop) practice. How to get a kid's imagination going!

Comment: 13 minutes and 37 seconds surely? :)

Comment: @JosephRogers, I like my number sequence better.  Though, coincidentally, your sequence was the street number of the house I grew up in.

Comment: @ShadoCat your number sequence is a fine choice, a strange coincidence with the house number, I was aiming at a geeky l33t speak reference for comic effect rather than seriously suggesting that it's objectively better

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking at this part of the question :

*"activating self-destruct mechanism **disengage coolant system** for the ship's main reactor, which then **increases the core temperature and triggers explosion [by destabilising core]**"* is it plausible?

The kind of reactor (or other power source) isn't specified.  Although fusion is suggested, it might not be fusion. Fission seems less likely. The question is generally whether ceasing cooling would ever plausibly provide a self destruct function.

I suspect the answer is "no":

### Engineering and power production principles

An explosion requires uncontrolled rapid "runaway" activity. That's a "fail = unsafe" principle. Fission and raw flame can be unsafe on failure of a protective system, but generally no power source aims to be. This isn't a feature you could add to create a self destruct. It's an inherent property of an engineering/power generation method. Fission is *inherently* capable of runaway. Fusion (as far as we know) *inherently* is not - at least not on less than star-size reactors, where gravity and opacity can create runaway. Other invented systems are however you wish them.

But the coolant system can only change a runaway-capable system from running as inhibited to uninhibited modes; it can't create a runaway capable system if none exists.

### Containment issues

Another problem is that most explosions need time to build up, however short. Even current nuclear weapons with an explosive effect (rather than just dirty material dispersion)  need a very tightly fitted and insanely precise engineered thick steel case, just to prevent the components simply melting or flying apart in the first fraction of a second. Think of a gun barrel or bullet case, used to contain the propellant as it turns to gas - same idea.

A power creating reactor doesn't typically have the kind of case needed and it probably wouldn't be compatible if desired. (Because even a small space would probably be enough to adversely affect the runaway force and make maintenance impractical, although this is obviously a bit speculative and could be handwaved away).

### Power *production* vs. power *storage*

To explode, you usually need to release some kind of stored energy, and this stored energy must be capable of being released very fast.

If the power system doesn't contain a *store* of power, or at least the ability to produce power fast enough, this makes it a bit less plausible. But if it can produce power quickly, then this still doesn't imply a store that can be released all at once. A bullet, rocket, or fission reactor contains stored energy that is designed or inherently capable of rapid release, but not all systems have this. Without much detail, this would probably be an issue to consider as well, in assessing plausibility.

### Failsafe designing

On principle, engineers tend to develop power systems that, on failure of control, are inherently safe not unsafe. You wouldn't want to fly a bomb. So your car systems have several hundred detectors (including code checks) that watch for risky engine status indicators and restrict rpm if so. (What if a switch stuck, or a detector was faulty?) Ditto all other power systems. Even your toaster's power circuit has a fuse somewhere.

But in addition they design for safety *even if active systems fail*. If your car battery fails and the electronics lose power, you dont want the engine to be left in a full-power state mechanically with no way to turn it off because of electronic control issues.

Coolant is a subsystem. You probably won't get engineers designing it to fail, because its so critical that the cooling system can *never* by accident (or due to some unlikely combination of faults),  fail.

Designing a bypassable safety system of this kind, with probable catastrophic effects, would be a bit like designing a lift ('elevator' in the US) for an office block where people work daily, and building in all safety features - plus an anti-terrorism feature that could raise it to the top floor at high speed and withdraw all safety controls (over cable drum rotation, lift car safety etc) and drop it at maximum speed to impact at the ground floor, just in case of a terrorist attack where the terrorists are in the lift.

In other words, however desireable a defence it might be, you just wouldn't design a safety critical system and a path that completely undermined it. You'd do it some different way.

### Possible alternative solutions

If the ship had some system that accumulated immense power, that power could be released in a specific manner. That's not a coolant failure but it would meet the needs of the question.

For example, suppose the ship has weapons, and these weapons were reliant on huge power delivery accumulated over a few seconds and released in a brief but immensely powerful burst. Then the power accumulators could be used as a source of self destruct, by providing a path that would release that power against the ship itself.

You'd have to think around the issues of containment (how do you stop the power transmission system just melting instead?) and impact (how would this lead to destruction rather than damage?)

Alternatively if the ship contained something that already had explosive effect, it would only be necessary to initiate whatever explodes it. Again that's not a coolant failure. For example if it carried some kind of torpedo weapons, or mining explosives, or a store of chemical fuel needed by some kind of pods which are too small for a reactor, or was powered by immensely dense matter in some kind of futuristic force-field, then you'd just have to set off the explosives, provide a (fail-safe!) detonator for the fuel store, or release the force-field.

But as stated, and looking at cooling systems only - no.

Answer (score 1):

There are generally two types of countdowns:

One is a timer counting down to a trigger action. This is the kind that can usually be aborted before it reaches zero, although there may be reasons to make the destruct irrevocable. When the timer reaches zero, detonation is essentially immediate.

The other type of countdown is a prediction. It is an estimated time at which the power source will go critical, containment will collapse, or whatever makes the thing go boom. Where this comes up, the surrounding science and technology always seems to be good enough to make such predictions down to the second.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Given standardized parts, ship designs, mechanisms, flow rates, temperature tolerances, and so on, predicting the reaction and the time it takes to kick off should be possible. In the case of military ships it would likely be tested for consistency.